# What's causing my HTML elements to appear with tons of inline JavaScript? How can I stop it?

Tags: html, javascript

I'm currently working on a page that uses a HTML wrapper supplied by the client. We inject our content into the wrapper and then render the page.

This wrapper links to other JavaScript libraries. When I inspect the element, I can see that one of my elements has been modified to appear as the following:

```
<li class="directory-result-text" fire="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" observe="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" stopObserving="function() {
      return __method.apply(null, [this].concat($A(arguments)));
    }" visible="function() {

    <!--..and it goes on like this for a while...-->

    }">
```

We use jQuery and none of our elements ever appear like this. Can somebody please tell me what might be causing this and how I can prevent it from happening to our content?

Comment: Can you show any of your jquery?

Comment: Which ide are you using?

Comment: It could be that the HTML wrapper you are using is adding it in. Can you give some more information?

Comment: looks like a mistake when assigning the event handler. We'd need to see the code that's doing the binding to know.

Comment: It looks like the wrapper is adding some custom attributes for it's own use. Apart from the verbosity and non-validity, is there a real problem?

Comment: @Ash, VS2010, but I don't think this is a problem. I've never seen this before in 3 years of web development. @Daniel, the jQuery isn't the issue. I don't have any on that page, other than the reference to the library. @aubreyrhodes, Ollie, This is the wrapper: `http://www.ft.com/global/mm0802/ag/wrapper`. @alohci, it's just ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the same thing here, a call to prototype's $() on an element does that, but I don't know why.

(only on IE btw)

after further looking, those attributes are all methods Prototype adds to extend the DOM, but when you add properties on an element object in IE, it seems that it adds them as attributes also.